# Compare class for priority queue

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

When we want a min priority queue, we declare `Compare` class as `std:greater`. Which is something like `return obj1 > obj2`

Could anyone elaborate how does priority queue use it?  Apply it in insertion? or use it for "heapify" after `pop()`.

We know in insertion, the new element would float up as much as possible. So If insertion uses greater, then `obj1` would be parent ? and `obj2` would be new element itself?

Comment: To all your questions, the answer is yes.

Comment: I don't know if the standard specifies the mechanism for sorting (I suspect is doesn't, although it may imply it) but it does specify some complexities. [`std::priority_queue::push`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/push),
 [`std::priority_queue::emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/emplace) and [`std::priority_queue::pop`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/pop) are all guaranteed to be at worst a logarithmic number of comparisons, plus the complexity of the matching operation on the underlying container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked up STL source code and get to know how is Compare function used. Below is the link
http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/algorithm

keyword: push_heap, sift_up

```
if (Compare(parent, children))
    do the swap
```

Comment: This answer should be a comment.